# "Оптимизация" графика

Tags: c++, qt

Дано: QVector содержащий QPointF точки графика, у которых значение по Y **округлено**
Необходимо оптимизировать точки, конкретно удалить те, которые имеют одинаковый темп роста с заданной пользователем точностью (qreal opt_accuracy от 0.01 до 1.0, чем меньше тем "аккуратнее" удаляются точки), чтобы из вот такого графика[image: вход]
получился вот такой
[image: итог]
или при таком

[image: вход1]

при точности 0.01 получился вот такой

[image: итог11]

при какой то большей точности красный или оранжевый даже

[image: итог12]

Что то похожее у меня получилось, в цикле берется по 3 точки, рассчитывается "левый" и "правый" темп роста, и их разность сравнивается с точностью, так же сравнивается их знак.

```
for (int center_index(1); center_index < graphic.count() - 1; center_index++) {

  int left_index(center_index - 1), right_index(center_index + 1);
  QPointF left_point(graphic.at(left_index)), center_point(graphic.at(center_index)), right_point(graphic.at(right_index));

  qreal left_time(std::abs(left_point.x() - center_point.x()));
  qreal left_dmc((center_point.y() - left_point.y()) / left_time);

  qreal right_time(std::abs(right_point.x() - center_point.x()));
  qreal right_dmc((right_point.y() - center_point.y()) / right_time);

  if (std::abs(left_dmc - right_dmc) < opt_accuracy && std::copysign(1, left_dmc) == std::copysign(1, right_dmc)) {

    graphic.remove(center_index, right_index - center_index);
    center_index--;
  }
}
```

код работает на таком графике как я нарисовал, но есть проблема, как я отметил, значения по Y округлены и иногда могут быть "ступенчатые" участки графика, например: { (100.73, 125), (123.04, 125), (123.07, 124) }, получается что у 0 и 1 точки рост нулевой, а у 1 и 2 рост -3, разность темпов роста слишком сильная чтобы "попасть в точность".

Еще я пробовал второй вариант, в котором я беру левый темп роста и проверяю станет ли левая точка равна правой, при таком темпе роста когда дойдет до правого Х, но этот метод удалял либо очень грубо либо наоборот оставляя некоторые лишние точки, не особо зависимо от точности

```
for (int center_index(1); center_index < graphic.count() - 1; center_index++) {

  int left_index(center_index - 1), right_index(center_index + 1);
  QPointF left_point(graphic.at(left_index)), center_point(graphic.at(center_index)), right_point(graphic.at(right_index));

  qreal left_time(std::abs(left_point.x() - center_point.x()));
  qreal left_dmc((center_point.y() - left_point.y()) / left_time);

  qreal time_diff(std::abs(right_point.x() - center_point.x()));

  if (std::abs((center_point.y() + left_dmc * time_diff) - right_point.y()) < opt_accuracy) {

    graphic.remove(center_index, right_index - center_index);
    center_index--;
  }
}
```

Мой код лучше не брать за основу, я уверен что это не совсем правильно, подскажите пожалуйста правильное решение.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Comment: спасибо! то что нужно